# Different output in two tables with the same <td> percentage

Tags: html, css, html-table, percentage

In this link http://jsfiddle.net/w9xxgxwm/4/ you can see my tables. The point is, I want that my  table (the 2nd one) have the exact size of the 1st table. I want that the borders matches with the 1st one.

The size of the `<td>` tags are the same, so I don't understand why the tables have different sizes.
The percentage attribute shouldn't be taking care of this problem?

The main table code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="2">Perfil</td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="2">Grupo EFR</td>
  <td colspan="2">EFR</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="2">Período de Vigência</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 6%">Cod Assoc</td>
  <td style="width: 6%">Codigo</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Descricao</td>
  <td style="width: 7%">Empresa</td>
  <td style="width: 6%">Codigo</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Descricao</td>
  <td style="width: 6%">Codigo</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Descricao</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Episódio</td>
  <td style="width: 3%">Exce.</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Inicio</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Fim</td>
  <td style="width: 3%">Preço</td>
  <td style="width: 9%">Observacao</td>
 </tr>
</table>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text"/></td>
   <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text"/></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 7%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 3%"><input type="text"/></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 3%"><input type="text" /></td>
   <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But you can see the output on the jsfiddle link I put.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using %?

Comment: if you're using the second table to let users input rows of data, then you might prefer to use javascript to append/insert a new row to the first table.

Comment: % is to have the table responsive to several screen sizes. Yes, it would be preferable, but I'd still like to read a answer to a 2 tables case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, [table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout) is “automatic”, which means that column widths are allocated by the browser according to the width requirements of cells. In this model, any widths that you set are taken just as suggested minimal widths.

To get “fixed table layout”, you can set `table { table-layout: fixed }`. But this is not sufficient in this case. Fixed layout means that the browser allocates column widths according to explicit settings on *columns* or, in their absence, according to width set for the cells of the *first row* or, in their absence too, divides the available width evenly for the columns. In this case, this would result in different column widths for the two tables.

A simple, though a bit brutal, way is to additionally use the following tags right after the the `<table ...>` tag of the first table, setting column widths equal to those of the second table:

```
<col style="width: 6%">
<col style="width: 6%">
<col style="width: 9%">
<col style="width: 7%">
<col style="width: 6%">
<col style="width: 9%">
<col style="width: 6%">
<col style="width: 9%">
<col style="width: 9%">
<col style="width: 3%">
<col style="width: 9%">
<col style="width: 9%">
<col style="width: 3%">
<col style="width: 9%">
```

A more elegant way would be to have just `<col>` tags without attributes and set the column widths in CSS (for both tables).

Anyway, fixed layout has a serious cost: it is fixed. The specified widths are used with no regard to cell contents. This means that if the content of a cell does not fit in, it will overflow and typically cover part of adjacent cell(s). You can affect this with the `overflow` property, but what could you do?

Setting widths in `em` or `ch` units might be a better approach, though still a shot in the dark. But it is difficult to suggest a better way without knowing what you are really trying to do (including the question where the percentages come from).

Comment: That's exact what I'm looking for, because my table will always be fixed. Brutal and forced, but still the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your table to have another row inside the same table, like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Perfil</td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Grupo EFR</td>
    <td colspan="2">EFR</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Período de Vigência</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 6%">Cod Assoc</td>
    <td style="width: 6%">Codigo</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Descricao</td>
    <td style="width: 7%">Empresa</td>
    <td style="width: 6%">Codigo</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Descricao</td>
    <td style="width: 6%">Codigo</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Descricao</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Episódio</td>
    <td style="width: 3%">Exce.</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Inicio</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Fim</td>
    <td style="width: 3%">Preço</td>
    <td style="width: 9%">Observacao</td>
  </tr>



    <tr>
       <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text"/></td>
       <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text"/></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 7%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 6%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 3%"><input type="text"/></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 3%"><input type="text" /></td>
       <td style="width: 9%"><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also cleaned and mdified your CSS a bit

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: table;
}
td {
    display:table-cell;
    width:auto;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nphmee41/)

Comment: It is correct! If I put it inside it works perfectly! Thanks, and it's indeed the best approach, but in this case I really need to have 2 tables, so I need to consider the answer bellow the correct one.